# Does tvOS support SignalR realtime updates?

Tags: signalr, tvos

I'm just getting started on a new project, and I'm trying to determine the technologies that I will need. Does the new tvOS framework support some kind of realtime updating when something happens on a remote server, like SignalR does?

I'm trying to find something that will work on the AppleTV as a kind of dashboard that reflects changes happening on an Azure Website. Thanks.

Comment: You could probably use web sockets in your tvOS app to send "real-time" messages from your server to the app.

Comment: There is a port of the SignalR client for Objective-C, but it is not official - https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC